# Render component by replacing selector

Tags: angular

Suppose I have a component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mycomponent',
  template: '...'
})
class MyComponent {
}
```

Normally it renders template under `<mycomponnent></mycomponent>`, is there a way I could let this component render but by replacing the selector? I saw https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html but not sure which configuration could lead to such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is (at least currently) not supported.

What you can do instead is using an attribute selector like

```ts
@Component({
  selector: '[mycomponent]',
  template: '...'
})
class MyComponent {
}
```

then it can be used with any tag like

```ts
<li mycomponent></li>
```

Comment: You mean if I use an attribute selector `<li mycomponent></li>` will be replaced by what's in `template`? I wonder why would selectors have different behaviors when it comes t rendering.

Comment: There is nothing being replaced but you (or the user of your component) can freely choose the element name that should become your component.